# Create Guice dependency injection binding in Scala function

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I want to bind a certain class, lets call it `injected` either to its real implementation `real` or to its `mock`.

Also side effects should happen and therefor a function would be preferable to encapsulate this work.

Doing that outside of a function is known. But that also requires the side effects to be coded multiple times

The functionality iam looking for could be outlined as this (none working approach!)

```
  private def bindMocksOptional(configSettingKey: String, injected: Class[_], real: Class[_] , mock: Class[_]) {
    configuration.getOptional[Boolean](configSettingKey) match {
      case Some(true) => {
        bind(injected).to(mock)
        val message = s"Using a mock (${mock.getCanonicalName})for ${injected.getCanonicalName}"
        Logger.warn(message)
        println(Console.MAGENTA + message)
      }
      case _ => bind(injected).to(real)
    }
  }
```

The function should take the outlined types as parameters, look up some config settings and based on those bind either to mock or real implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Provider](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings):

```scala
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Guice, Inject, Provider}

class Configuration {
  def getOptional[T](key: String): Option[T] = None
}

trait DatabaseClient

class DatabaseClientMock extends DatabaseClient
class DatabaseClientReal extends DatabaseClient

// ---

// 1. Define Guice Provider:
class DatabaseClientGuiceProvide @Inject()(configuration: Configuration)
    extends Provider[DatabaseClient] {
  override def get(): DatabaseClient = {
    configuration.getOptional[Boolean]("mock") match {
      case Some(true) =>
        println("used mock")
        new DatabaseClientMock
      case _ =>
        println("used real")
        new DatabaseClientReal
    }
  }
}

class MainModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    // 2. Bind dependencies of provider
    bind(classOf[Configuration]).toInstance(new Configuration)

    // 3. Bind provider
    bind(classOf[DatabaseClient])
      .toProvider(classOf[DatabaseClientGuiceProvide])
  }
}


// 4. Test it:
object GuiceMain extends App {
  val module = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule)

  println(module.getInstance(classOf[DatabaseClient]))
}
```